# Wikipedia svg icon to new size

Tags: svg

This is a sample of one of the existing icons in my svg file:

```
<symbol id="icon-stumbleupon" viewBox="0 0 34 32">
<path class="path1" d="M18.964 12.714v-2.107q0-0.75-0.536-1.286t-1.286-0.536-1.286 0.536-0.536 1.286v10.929q0 3.125-2.25 5.339t-5.411 2.214q-3.179 0-5.42-2.241t-2.241-5.42v-4.75h5.857v4.679q0 0.768 0.536 1.295t1.286 0.527 1.286-0.527 0.536-1.295v-11.071q0-3.054 2.259-5.214t5.384-2.161q3.143 0 5.393 2.179t2.25 5.25v2.429l-3.482 1.036zM28.429 16.679h5.857v4.75q0 3.179-2.241 5.42t-5.42 2.241q-3.161 0-5.411-2.223t-2.25-5.366v-4.786l2.339 1.089 3.482-1.036v4.821q0 0.75 0.536 1.277t1.286 0.527 1.286-0.527 0.536-1.277v-4.911z"></path>
</symbol>
```

I found [this](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Wikipedia%27s_W.svg) wikipedia svg icon (128 × 128 pixels) I would like to add to my svg icon file.

I tried to add it like this:

```
<symbol id="icon-wikipedia" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
<path class="path1" d="M 120.85,29.21 C 120.85,29.62 120.72,29.99 120.47,30.33 C 120.21,30.66 119.94,30.83 119.63,30.83 C 117.14,31.07 115.09,31.87 113.51,33.24 C 111.92,34.6 110.29,37.21 108.6,41.05 L 82.8,99.19 C 82.63,99.73 82.16,100 81.38,100 C 80.77,100 80.3,99.73 79.96,99.19 L 65.49,68.93 L 48.85,99.19 C 48.51,99.73 48.04,100 47.43,100 C 46.69,100 46.2,99.73 45.96,99.19 L 20.61,41.05 C 19.03,37.44 17.36,34.92 15.6,33.49 C 13.85,32.06 11.4,31.17 8.27,30.83 C 8,30.83 7.74,30.69 7.51,30.4 C 7.27,30.12 7.15,29.79 7.15,29.42 C 7.15,28.47 7.42,28 7.96,28 C 10.22,28 12.58,28.1 15.05,28.3 C 17.34,28.51 19.5,28.61 21.52,28.61 C 23.58,28.61 26.01,28.51 28.81,28.3 C 31.74,28.1 34.34,28 36.6,28 C 37.14,28 37.41,28.47 37.41,29.42 C 37.41,30.36 37.24,30.83 36.91,30.83 C 34.65,31 32.87,31.58 31.57,32.55 C 30.27,33.53 29.62,34.81 29.62,36.4 C 29.62,37.21 29.89,38.22 30.43,39.43 L 51.38,86.74 L 63.27,64.28 L 52.19,41.05 C 50.2,36.91 48.56,34.23 47.28,33.03 C 46,31.84 44.06,31.1 41.46,30.83 C 41.22,30.83 41,30.69 40.78,30.4 C 40.56,30.12 40.45,29.79 40.45,29.42 C 40.45,28.47 40.68,28 41.16,28 C 43.42,28 45.49,28.1 47.38,28.3 C 49.2,28.51 51.14,28.61 53.2,28.61 C 55.22,28.61 57.36,28.51 59.62,28.3 C 61.95,28.1 64.24,28 66.5,28 C 67.04,28 67.31,28.47 67.31,29.42 C 67.31,30.36 67.15,30.83 66.81,30.83 C 62.29,31.14 60.03,32.42 60.03,34.68 C 60.03,35.69 60.55,37.26 61.6,39.38 L 68.93,54.26 L 76.22,40.65 C 77.23,38.73 77.74,37.11 77.74,35.79 C 77.74,32.69 75.48,31.04 70.96,30.83 C 70.55,30.83 70.35,30.36 70.35,29.42 C 70.35,29.08 70.45,28.76 70.65,28.46 C 70.86,28.15 71.06,28 71.26,28 C 72.88,28 74.87,28.1 77.23,28.3 C 79.49,28.51 81.35,28.61 82.8,28.61 C 83.84,28.61 85.38,28.52 87.4,28.35 C 89.96,28.12 92.11,28 93.83,28 C 94.23,28 94.43,28.4 94.43,29.21 C 94.43,30.29 94.06,30.83 93.32,30.83 C 90.69,31.1 88.57,31.83 86.97,33.01 C 85.37,34.19 83.37,36.87 80.98,41.05 L 71.26,59.02 L 84.42,85.83 L 103.85,40.65 C 104.52,39 104.86,37.48 104.86,36.1 C 104.86,32.79 102.6,31.04 98.08,30.83 C 97.67,30.83 97.47,30.36 97.47,29.42 C 97.47,28.47 97.77,28 98.38,28 C 100.03,28 101.99,28.1 104.25,28.3 C 106.34,28.51 108.1,28.61 109.51,28.61 C 111,28.61 112.72,28.51 114.67,28.3 C 116.7,28.1 118.52,28 120.14,28 C 120.61,28 120.85,28.4 120.85,29.21 z"></path>
</symbol>
```

But the size is to big, how do I match the size of the icons in my svg file?

Comment: Change `viewBox` to `0 0 128 128`.

Comment: It might be worthwhile having a read of this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox